# Is there is a way to reformate integer number to specific formate?

Tags: java, string, formatting, integer

I need to reformate integer to be four letters in length by adding zeros to the left of that integers value like  "435" to "0435"

and "2" to "0002"

i can do it by playing a game with if and else cases... but Is theres is a better way to do that ?

Comment: `while (n.length() < 4) { n = '0'+n;}` (where `n` is the integer in `String` form) would be one possible way.

Comment: Just for fun, as an alternative to `String.format`: `("0000" + input).substring(input.length());`

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format`

```
String filledZeros = String.format("%04d", yourNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is useful

```
  int number = 15;
  String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  while(sb.length()+numberAsString.length()<10) {
     sb.append('0');
  }
  sb.append(number);
  String paddedNumberAsString = sb.toString();
  System.out.println(paddedNumberAsString);
```